# Mock Android Application class for tests using Robolectric in App with Dagger 2

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, dagger-2

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to testing and my current task is to fix an issue that stops already existing tests from running.

Several tests using `Robolectric` are failing with the error message

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.robolectric.internal.ShadowProvider: Provider org.robolectric.Shadows not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
```

I read in [this](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1766) Github post that this error can happen if there are issues with the environment configuration. After some testing I could narrow down the problem to two methods in the `Application class`, `initPicasso` and `initJobDispatcher`, which initialize `Picasso` and a `Firebase` job that is running now and then

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        AndroidThreeTen.init(this);

        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        initPicasso();

        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this)).build();

        initJobDispatcher();
    }

    void initPicasso() {
        final String PICASSO_CACHE = "picasso-cache";

        File cacheDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), PICASSO_CACHE);
        if (!cacheDir.exists()) {
            //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }

        Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDir, 50 * 1024 * 1024);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message) {
                Timber.d("XYZ" + message);
            }
        });
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();

        Picasso.setSingletonInstance(
                new Picasso.Builder(this)
                        .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {

                            }
                        })
                        .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(client))
                        .build()
        );
    }

    void initJobDispatcher() {
        Driver myDriver = new GooglePlayDriver(this);
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(myDriver);

        Timber.d("Setting up Job at: %s", LocalDateTime.now().toString());

        Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(SyncJobService.class)
                .setTag("my-job-tag")
                .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(15, 25))
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
                .setRecurring(false)
                .build();

        int result = dispatcher.schedule(job);
        if (result != FirebaseJobDispatcher.SCHEDULE_RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Timber.e("Job could not be scheduled: %d", result);
        }
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
        return applicationComponent;
    }
}
```

If I comment out these two methods, the tests will run fine.

**Now my question is:**
How can I mock the `Application class` or at least these two methods?
I tried to create a test `Application class` which overrides these methods, but that didn't help.

```
public class MyApplicationTest extends Application {

    void initPicasso() {
        //do nothing here
        System.out.println("Using the MyApplicationTest application");
    }

    void initJobDispatcher() {
        //do nothing here
    }
}
```

Or as this project is using `Dagger2`, are there ways using dagger to mock the `Application class`? As this area is absolutely new to me, any advices or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you added the tag application in the config annotation such as
    @RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
    @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, application = MyApplicationTest.class)